# Regex for validating comma separated java fields, referenced fields, and Sets

Tags: java, regex

I have a code which parses comma separated names of java class fields, and optionally field names with class names and dot operator(i.e. foreign fields) and also set/array like notation to refer to multiple foreign fields without using class name multiple times: e.g. following are valid scenarios:

1. MyField1,MyField2,AnotherClass.ACField1,AnotherClass2[AC2Field1,AC2Field2,AC2Field3]
2. MyField1,MyField2

I have written following regex/java code:
But see the last line in main method (i.e. first example above). It should be valid but regex is not matching.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {

  static Pattern fieldListPattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)(([.,]\\w+)|([\\[]\\w+([,]?\\w+)[\\]]))*$");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    validate("MyField1,MyField2"); // valid
    validate("ABC,A.CDE"); // valid
    validate("ABC"); // valid
    validate("ABC,CDE"); // valid
    validate("ABC.CDE"); // valid
    validate("ABC,.CDE"); // XXXXXXX
    validate("ABC.,CDE"); // XXXXXXX
    validate(",ABC,CDE"); // XXXXXXX
    validate(",ABC"); // XXXXXXX
    validate(".ABC"); // XXXXXXX
    validate(".ABC.CDE"); // XXXXXXX
    validate(".ABC,CDE"); // XXXXXXX
    validate(",ABC.CDE"); // XXXXXXX

    // arrays

    validate("ABC[CDE]"); // Valid
    validate("ABC[]"); // XXXXXXX
    validate("ABC.[CDE]"); // XXXXXXX
    validate("MyField1,MyField2,AnotherClass.ACField1,AnotherClass2[AC2Field1,AC2Field2]"); // Valid
    validate("MyField1,MyField2,AnotherClass.ACField1,AnotherClass2[AC2Field1,AC2Field2,AC2Field3]"); // This should be valid, but coming as invalid
  }

  static void validate(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    fieldListPattern.matcher("").matches();
    System.out.println("Valid ? " + fieldListPattern.matcher(s).matches());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a pattern, you can optionally repeat matching from an opening till closing square bracket:

```
^\w+(?:\[\w+(?:,\w+)*\])?(?:[.,]\w+(?:\[\w+(?:,\w+)*\])?)*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
- `(?:\[\w+(?:,\w+)*\])?` Optionally match word characters separated by a comma in between square brackets
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[.,]` Match either `.` or `,`
  - `\w+(?:\[\w+(?:,\w+)*\])*`
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TYhhuX/1)

In Java with the double escaped backslashes:

```
String regex = "^\\w+(?:\\[\\w+(?:,\\w+)*\\])?(?:[.,]\\w+(?:\\[\\w+(?:,\\w+)*\\])?)*$";
```

Comment: Perfect, actually I figured out myself about repeat. But your regex also handles a lot of other valid scenarios, which mine was missing. Thanks!